# Android: Get the latitude/longitude of a draggable marker in (Here) Nokia Maps?

Tags: android, here-api

I used Here Map to make an android traffic app, and I want to retrieve the coordinate of the marker while I'm dragging the marker in the map control. 
How I can do that in android OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry at the moment the current dragged position is not exposed externally. The current position of the MapMarker is only updated in the public API when the marker drag ends. I'll make a note of this so we can expose it in an upcoming release of the SDK.

Meanwhile, you can will need to add a View.onTouchListener and capture the current X-Y coordinate during a move event. Use Map#pixelToGeo to convert the pixel back to a GeoCoordinate for the current location.